# Supermicro server can't turn on after I disconnect IEC power cord cable without turning off the mains

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, repair

I did this and after that my server can't turn on.  The thing is that I actually turned off the server from Windows before disconnecting the power cable. There's no burnt smell. I tried changing to another power cable but to no avail.  I did this a couple times in the past without any issue, and I remembered doing this to PCs multiple times without breaking any of them, so I'm quite surprised this happened.

I'd like to add that this server has an IPMI feature so it's possible that power is still supplied to the server even though Windows is turned off.  Maybe this is why the power supply shorted?

Has anyone experienced something similar and what's the solution?  Grateful for any advice.

Supermicro Chassis - https://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/1u/504/SC504-203B

Power supply - PWS-203-1H - https://store.supermicro.com/media/wysiwyg/productspecs/PWS-203-1H/PWS-203-1H_quick_spec.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many power supplies does the server have, a.d sre they all active? Why do you say you have shoreted the cable, and if you did so, have you checked the power board fuse? Pulling a power cable out a computer wont cause a cable fault. IPMI requires a power source to run.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for replying.  It only has 1 power supply and it's dead - I mean, there's no LED lights even when I turned on power.  I'm not a hardware person so I don't really know if it's fused for sure.  I've updated the topic with some photos of the power supply and motherboard.  "Pulling a power cable out a computer wont cause a cable fault." - yes, I thought so as well and have done this previously without any issue - but this time for unknown reason, it didn't work.  By the way, I remembered hearing some static sounds when connecting and disconnecting the power supply.

Comment: I posit the power supply went faulty while it was runnong, but this did not become apparent until ypu attempted to stop and start it. Its also possible that ehen you plugged it in/unplugged it you did not do so cleanly and the power supply got multiple doses of inrush current and cpuld.not handle it. This would be bad power supply design - this is not your fault.

Comment: Before replacing the powrr supply (which is probably required), check that thete is power coming from the wall and also leave the power supply unplugged for a couple.of hours, then try plugging it in again. If there is a blown polyfuse in it this could restore power.

Comment: @davidgo I found the problem, the fuse on both power cables I tested with blew.  I was able to power on using a 3rd power cable which I found.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by using a 3rd power cable which I found.